# Are multiple WeakReferences to the same object always in sync?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, garbage-collection

If there are more than one WeakReference pointing to the same object, will they always be cleared at the same time, or may they be out of sync. A small example to illustrate:

```
var o = new Object();
var weak1 = new WeakReference(o);
var weak2 = new WeakReference(o);

for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    GC.Collect();
    Debug.Assert(weak1.IsAlive == weak2.IsAlive);
}
```

**P.S.** The above snipped runs fine (the assert is not triggered). Also the questions is really (at least) two separate issues:

- Are they cleared approximately at the same time (not thread safe)?
- Are they cleared in a thread safe manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here in your question, `weak1.IsAlive` always equals to `weak2.IsAlive`, because [WeakReference.IsAlive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.isalive.aspx) gets an indication whether the object referenced by the current WeakReference object (or say, [WeakRefernce.Target](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.target.aspx)) has been garbage collected. The two WeakReference have the same target object. But be aware of that *weak1/weak2* themselves are also reference type, they are not reference equal, but their targets are the same.

Comment: Though it isn't documented to be that way, the two WeakReferences allocate different handles internally, and I'm not sure it is documented that a garbage collection clears *all* weak references either. Basically, yes, it sure looks that way, but no, I wouldn't build code that relied on it.

Comment: @Lasse - that was the kind of information I was looking for. What promises are actually made? Is at a bad idea to have multiple WeakReferences to the same object, or? My gut feeling is that it is?!?

Comment: I don't think it is a bad idea to keep multiple references around, but if you need every reference to disappear at the same time, so that you can guarantee that you don't build a new instance in one place and use the old one in another place, then I would definitely try to avoid this.